# How can I get email updates on questions I post?

Tags: support, notifications, user-accounts, email

How do I subscribe to receive email updates on comments and answers to questions that I post? Preferably this would be enabled by default on any new question I post. It used to be the case, but for some reason I’ve received no email for a few weeks (and I have changed nothing).

I see many other lengthy discussions of this, which all seem to be out of date (their screenshots don’t match what I see).

When I visit one of my posted questions, I see no option to subscribe.

When I visit my Stack Exchange profile and click “Inbox”, it lists several items I have not been emailed, but it offers no option to subscribe.

When I visit my Stack Overflow profile and click “Settings”, then “Edit Email Settings”, I see “Inbox: Answers to your questions, comments, chat notifications, and more” is set to the most frequent option, “3 hrs”, but I am getting nothing.

Comment: I am commenting here in case it helps me get notified of future activity on this post.